# If this functions calls, do something php

Tags: php

I have a function in php which looks like this:

```
function blabla(){

    // some code

    if(/*function dothis() calls me*/){

        // do this
    }

    return something;
}
```

And I have two functions who call `blabla()`. When the first function calls `blabla()`, I want that the code outside the if-statement executes. And when the function `dothis()` calls `blabla()`, then the code inside the if-statement should be called. How do I build my if-statement?

Comment: You don't want functions to change behaviour depending on the call stack, really. That would make your code impossible to test reliably, and would definitely make things slower than they need to be. If you need to do 2 different things, write 2 functions.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, that's right what your are saying. This was the best solution anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pass a boolean as an argument to `blabla`. In `dothis` you can call `blabla(true)` and in the other function you can call `blabla(false)`. Check the argument in the if statement and then the code inside will only be executed when `blabla` is called from `dothis`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try like this:-

function blabla($val = 0){

```
// some code

if($val){

    // do this
}

return something;
```

}

now if i call blabla function from two ways:-

blabla(0); - In this case if statement will not execute.
blabla(1); - In this case if statement will execute.